# How to use or call a static variable declared in another class

Tags: c#, static

I have the following Main class where it initialize a static List at the beginning as follows,

```
class Program
{
    static List<Student> stdlist;
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        stdlist = new List<Student>();
        Login login = new Login();
        login.showLogin();
    }
} 

class Login
{
    public void showLogin()
    {
        // Here i want to get that List, How can I call it
    }
}
```

How should I call the list variable from class Login? Please help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default access modifier in C# is `private`, so you must explicitly mark the field as `public`.

```
class Program
{
    public static List<Student> stdlist;
}
```

Now, whether or not that's a good design decision is up for debate, but that's neither her nor there.

Answer (score 0):

```
class Program
    {
        public static List<Student> stdlist;
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            stdlist = new List<Student>();
            Login login = new Login();
            login.showLogin();
        }
    } 

class Login{

public void showLogin(){

   Program.stdlist //access the list like so
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to read **[Access Modifiers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wxh6fsc7.aspx)** in C#, this will help you to understand this topic.

Read **Public** in that.